# Loading a MySQL Database into Java Swing Application

Tags: java, mysql, swing, minecraft, bukkit

I have a MySQL database that i am trying to load into a java application i am making. It is to  show the current online players in a minecraft server. I have it setup to where the Server updates the database when a person leaves or joins. I need it to load into a control panel that shows online players, and allows the to stop/start/restart the server.

Thanks

Comment: What is the platform u r working on? Windows/Linux/Mac?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Swing Framework and only want to connect to a database you need the driver and the jdbc to manage the connections. [Here you can download the driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

And for using it, I'll link you the MySQL's manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j.html).

Another thing: Once, I needed to make a kind of time line like twitter's and surfing in the web I fount one or two articles where they explained how to make SQL Server produce a sort of signal to make you know a new register is in the data base and then you can update your data in real time, but as that was a DBA job and we had no DBA, I had to use a thread which automatically updated every 60000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

What have you done till now, any SSCCE?

Here is the code that shows how to retrive data's from mySQL database:

```
public void selectFromSomeTable(){
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://nameOfTheHost/yourDBname";
    String dbUsr = "dbUsername";
    String dbPass = "dbPassword";
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl,dbUsr,dbPass);
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM someTable");
        while(rs.next()){
            //Get values
            String someValue =rs.getString("name_of_the_column");
            .
            .
            .
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            st.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is all I can do for you now.